# getting a good sample of pixels from an image

Tags: image, sampling

lets say I have a big image with about 90% greenish pixels, 9% bluish pixels and 1% brownish pixels. I want to get a sample of only 100 pixels from the whole image having around maybe 2000,000 pixels.

I don't want the sample to contain pixels relative to their frequency in the original image, rather it should have equal number of greenish, bluish and brownish pixels.

I use -ish after every color because the pixels have different values and also this would be easy to do if I knew the colors of each image, Each image has different color groups so I need to come up with a general way of doing this which does not depend on me specifying the colors of the image.

Comment: are the pixels randomly distributed on your original image or not? For example, can your image have 900 000 greenish pixels, then 90 000 blueish ones, then 10 000 brownish one on the last 10 lines.  In other words, if you're image is, say, 1000 pixels wide, can the 10 000 brownish ones be all at the bottom, filling the last ten lines?

Comment: oh wait...  What if out of one million pixels you have one unique red pixel, do you want that red pixel to appear in your sample?

Comment: By "sample", do you mean a 10x10 block of neighboring pixels?

Comment: The type of sample desired is understood: it must be one which provides an even number of representatives of each color _category_ (red-ish, brown-ish...) regardless of the relative overall count of each of the these categories' representatives. The question is ambiguous, however: Are you trying to find a sampling method to be applied to an unseen image, or are you trying to produce such a sample for an image which you have previously analyzed.

Comment: wizardofodds : the pixels are randomly distributed, for your second question I should have mentioned that I have to pass the number of groups I want from the image, so for this image I would say 3 and it should ignore the lone red pixel and just give me clumps of three heaviest occuring colors.



mikewyatt : I have to pass this sample to a clustering algorithm which is too time intensive so the max I can run is 50x50 image block of neighbouring pixels. Thats why I am trying to get a good sample from the bigger image so that I can run data clustering on smaller sample and get good exemplars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 megapixel is 8MB at 32-bits per pixel.

You could treat the 2D array of pixels as a 1D list of numbers and sort it.

Then take every n'th pixel from the sorted list.